# Automatically inferring dtypes and min_itemsize on large datasets iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

In my line of work I am often given a large csv file with no information at all regarding the contents or formats. I am trying to develop a workflow to automatically infer both the datatypes of the columns as well as the maximum-string lengths for object dtypes with the end goal of storing the formatted dataset in an HDFStore. I am looking for help to come up with the best practice for this scenario. I have something that works, but it seems inefficient:

The data for this example can be found here: http://www.kaggle.com/c/loan-default-prediction/data

```
import pandas as pd

# first pass to determine file formats using pd.read_csv inference
fmts = []
chunker = pd.read_csv('../data/train.csv', chunksize=10000)

for chunk in chunker:
    fmts.append(chunk.dtypes)

fmts = reduce(lambda x,y: x.combine(y, max), fmts)
```

This previous snippet accumulates the inferred dtypes for each chunk and then reduces them taking the max:

```
In[1]:fmts[:10]
Out[1]: 
id      int64
f1      int64
f2      int64
f3    float64
f4      int64
f5      int64
f6      int64
f7    float64
f8    float64
f9    float64
dtype: object
```

So step one is complete. I have created a list of data types that can be passed to `read_csv` on subsequent runs.  Now to find the maximum length of the `object` columns which will be stored as `string` in the `HDFStore`:

```
# second pass now get max lengths of objects
objs = fmts[fmts == 'object'].index
cnvt = {obj : str for obj in objs}
lens = []

chunker = pd.read_csv('../data/train.csv', chunksize=10000,
                      converters=cnvt, usecols=objs)
for chunk in chunker:
    for col in chunk:
        lens.append(chunk.apply(lambda x: max(x.apply(len))))

# reduce the lens into one
lens = dict(reduce(lambda x,y: x.combine(y, max), lens))
```

I now have a dictionary where the columns of type object are the keys and the maximum cell length across all chunks is the value:

```
In[2]:lens
Out[2]: 
{'f137': 20,
 'f138': 26,
 'f206': 20,
 'f207': 27,
 'f276': 20,
 'f277': 27,
 'f338': 26,
 'f390': 32,
 'f391': 42,
 'f419': 20,
 'f420': 26,
 'f466': 19,
 'f469': 27,
 'f472': 35,
 'f534': 27,
 'f537': 35,
 'f626': 32,
 'f627': 42,
 'f695': 22,
 'f698': 22}
```

My final step is to then use the inferred formats and lengths to store everything in an HDFStore table:

```
# Lastly loop through once more to append to an HDFStore table!
store = pd.HDFStore("../data/train.h5")

chunker = pd.read_csv('../data/train.csv', chunksize=10000, dtype=dict(fmts))
for chunk in chunker:
    store.append('train', chunk, min_itemsize=lens)
```

Does this workflow make sense? What do others do to work with large datasets that don't fit in memory and need to be stored on disk in an HDFStore?

Comment: Its 'easier' to simply set a max string size that you know you won't violate, and just use float types; then you don't really need even to do this. Its a tad inefficient for strings, but compression helps.

Comment: How do I determine which columns are objects, though? Should I still make the first pass to determine the inferred column types and just forget the second pass to calculate lengths of object columns?

Comment: You don't need to if you simply pass a ``min_itemsize=40`` (or whatever number is 'big enough'), this will apply to all object columns, alternatively, you can use: ``df.dtypes`` to see which are object (the values are the dtype)

Comment: Furthermore, say that you decide that the resultant file size is too big because you are using a really large ``min_itemsize``; after your file is written, have another routine to post-process it (to create another one), which uses the max column size. I often have a pipeline things to do with a hdf file; some require all of the data know in advance (so I chunk thru it and do what I need), then in the next step use that info to create a new file and write it. Unless you are really at a space premium, use of compression and a reasonable guess at min_itemsize should prob work.

Comment: I think the problem I have is that by using chunksize and writing to an HDFStore, the column dtypes can be different. Something that looks like a float in the first chunk, might be an object in the next. That's the problem I was having and trying to overcome by determining the true data types ahead of time.

Comment: sure..that's possible...a block of 'ints' can instanlly turn to float if the first nan is in the 2nd chunk.....that's easy to fix (just make all floats)